# Searching a 2D Javascript Array For Value Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a jQuery that will find the index of a specific value within a 7x7 2D array.

So if the value I am looking for is 0 then I need the function to search the 2D array and once it finds 0 it stores the index of the two indexes.

This is what I have so far, but it returns "0 0" (the initial values set to the variable.

Here is a jsFiddle and the function I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/31pj8ydz/1/

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var items = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
                 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
                 [1,2,3,0,5,6,7], 
                 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
                 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
                 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
                 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]];

    var row = 0;
    var line = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            if (items[i, j] == '0,') {
                row = i;
                line = j;
            }
        }
    }

    $('.text').text(row + ' ' + line);
});
```

HTML:

```
<p class="text"></p>
```

Comment: multidimension indexers in javascript are `[][]`, ie `items[i][j]`

Comment: i think the correct terms are row and collumn instead of row and line (line == row)

Comment: You're also not incrementing or checking `j` in the inner `for` loop.

Comment: updated my answer, with some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are following problems in the code

**1)** `items[i,j]` should be `items[i][j]`.

**2)** You are comparing it with `'0,'` it should be `0` or `'0'`, if you are not concerned about type.

**3)** In your inner `for` loop you should be incrementing `j` and testing `j` as exit condition.

Change your `for` loop like bellow and it will work

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (items[i][j] == '0') {
                row = i;
                line = j;
            }
        }
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/31pj8ydz/3/)

**Note:-**

**1)** Better to use `===` at the place of `==`, it checks for type also. As you see with `0=='0'` gives true.

**2)** Better to say `i < items.length` and `j<items[i].length` instead of hard-coding it as 7.

Comment: Thanks !! I tried fixing all the errors in my code but the page became completely unresponsive. It was the change of ++i, ++j to i++, j++ that fixed that

Answer (score 1):

You access your array with the wrong way. Please just try this one:

```
items[i][j]
```

When we have a multidimensional array we access the an element of the array, using `array[firstDimensionIndex][secondDimensionIndex]...[nthDimensionIndex]`.

That being said, you should change the condition in your if statement:

```
 if( items[i][j] === 0 )
```

Please notice that I have removed the `,` you had after 0. It isn't needed. Also I have removed the `''`. We don't need them also.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is comparing

```
if (items[i, j] == '0,')
```

Accessing is wrong, you should use `[i][j]`.

And your array has values:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
....
```

Your value `'0,'` is a string, which will not match numeric values inside the array, meaning that your row and line won't change.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are accessing your array wrong. To access a 2D array, you use the format `items[i][j]`.

Second, your array doesn't contain the value `'0'`. It doesn't contain any strings. So the `row` and `line` variables are never changed.

You should change your if statement to look like this:

```
if(items[i][j] == 0) {
```

Notice it is searching for the number 0, not the string '0'.

Comment: actually, it contains the value '0'

Comment: @andre On second look, it does contain the number 0, but it doesn't contain the string '0', which is what the OP was searching for. I fixed my answer.

Comment: actually, the comparison operator used allow to compare a string against an integer, unless the comparison operator was ===

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo;
items.forEach(function(arr, i) {
    arr.forEach(function(val, j) {
        if (!val) { //0 coerces to false
            foo = [i, j];
        }
    }
}
```

Here foo will be the last instance of 0 in the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing loop wrong 
On place of

```
 for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            if (items[i, j] == '0,') {
                row = i;
                line = j;
            }
        }
    }
```

use this

```
 for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (items[i][j] == 0) {
                row = i;
                line = j;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/31pj8ydz/4/)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are still learning how to program. But here is an algorithm I've made. Analyze it and compare to your code ;)

```
var itens = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
             [1,2,3,0,5,6,7], 
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]];

var row = null;
var collumn = null;

for (var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < itens[i].length; j++) {
        if (itens[i][j] == 0) {
            row = i;
            collumn = j;
        }
    }
}

console.log(row, collumn);
```